# Mountain Lion is stuck with "See network administrator" when joining Wi-Fi network

Tags: macos, wifi

I recently clean installed Mountain Lion to my mid 2011 iMac, and ran into a frustrating issue when joining my Wi-Fi network. All my other Apple devices have no trouble accessing the same wifi, except this very iMac. The typical error message is either "See network administrator" or "Connection time out"

I did try to update the iMac to the latest (10.8.2 at the time of writing), and I still can't join the WiFi.

On the same iMac, if I reboot and boot into ubuntu Live CD, I was able to join the WiFi using the same internal wireless card. It leads me to think that something is off with Mountain Lion.

The router currently uses WPA2. I also did a wifi analysis and picked a channel that is least used by nearby routers.

I also spent quite sometime doing research. I cleaned up the Keychain-access, and I removed and re-added the network within the Wi-Fi network settings. I also make sure that SSID of my router has no "-" or any other weird characters. I also reset my router a few times, but it didn't help

The iMac came with Lion, and the WiFi connection to the same router wasn't all the stable, but at least I was able to connect. With Mountain Lion, nada no dice, not even connecting once

I am running out of ideas, and the current workaround is to rely on wired cable directly to the router. Or if I really want a stable wifi on this iMac, ubuntu. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue on my MacBook Pro with one particular WIFI connection. It was giving me the "Connection time out" error message.

I was able to workaround it by:

1) Removing the WIFI connection: *System Preferences* > *Network* > *WIFI* > *Advanced* > *Select the relevant connection and click the "-" sign* > *Click "Show All" or close the window*.

2) Adding the connection manually: *System Preferences* > *Network* > *WIFI* > *Advanced* > *Click on the "+" sign* > *Enter the connection settings manually*.

This has worked for me and that particular connection never gave me issues afterwards.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Melwan, thanks for the tip. That's actually one of the first things I tried. I went even further by cleaning out all the cached passwords for my network under the Keychain-access. Still no dice.

Comment: Have you tried changing the channel of the connection from within the router settings? Channel 11 seems to act up for my setup. I usually set it up for Channel 6 or 1.

Comment: Yep, based on the wifi survey (InSSIDer on a separate working Windows box), I have switched to a least used channel. both 1 and 11 are fairly occupied, so I have chosen 6. Still no go.

Comment: Does your working account have administrator privileges? If it doesn't, log in as an admin and set up the wifi connection.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out the issue has to do with the incompatible router itself
zyxel nbg-416n with the latest firmware appears to reject the iMac somehow.

When I switched to another router d-link running openwrt, iMac connects just fine. So the solution was to switch router